# Скрытый input в python 3.8

Tags: python, input, python-3.8

Как сделать, чтобы input был скрыт или заменён на другой символ

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/getpass.html

Comment: Вообще не понятна суть вопроса. Разверните, пожалуйста. И почитайте раздел справки о том. как задавать хорошие вопросы

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужен модуль getpass
И вместо input() использовать getpass.getpass()
(Ну или можно присвоить переменную этому методу)

Answer (score 1):

```
import getpass
yourinput = getpass.getpass()
print(yourinput)
```