# Bвод пароля, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, print, delete

Например у меня есть такой код:

```py
print ('Type password')
password = input ('>>> ')
```

Вводит пользователь пароль...

```
Type password
>>> anyPassword
```

Я хочу, чтобы ввод пользователя скрывался.
Желательно, чтобы работало в `IDLE`.

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка около ответа.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139293/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-input-%D0%B2-python-3-8

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1030302/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995019/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
```

Comment: Может есть способы скрыть текст в IDLE?

Comment: @Pythoncoder нет...